# calculating total with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on an app the tracks the number of beds in hospitals around my area. I am using Redux to access the state of each hospital bed. I am trying to add the total number of each specific bed, and the total number of all the beds in the hospital and have redux change the total number as a bed becomes taken and returned. How would I be able to add each bed together, while also changing the total number if a bed becomes taken or returned? I can try to explain if anymore information is needed. Thanks in advance for all the help!

ActionCreators in my redux folder:

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const SWMCFH = (id, name, availableMed) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.TOTAL_MED_BED,
    payload: {
    id : id,
    name: name,
    availableMed : availableMed,
    }
});
```

ActionTypes in redux folder:

```
export const TAKE_BED = "TAKE_BED";
export const TOTAL_MED_BED = "TOTAL_MED_BED"
```

Reducer in my redux folder:

```
import * as ActionTypes from '../actions/ActionTypes';

const SWMCFHState = {
    id : "SWMC",
    name: "Swedish Medical Center First Hill",
    availableMed :{
        total: 10,
        A14: 1,
        A13: 1,
        A12: 1,
        B19: 1,
        B24: 1,
        B27: 1,
        C10: 1,
        C11: 1,
        C16: 1, 
        D12: 1
    },
    availableTele: {
        total: 5,
        A20: 1,
        A24: 1,
        B03: 1,
        B04: 1,
        B05: 1
    },
    availableIcu: {
        total: 3,
        C01: 1,
        C02: 1,
        C06: 1
    }
};

export  const SWMCFH = (state = SWMCFHState , action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.TOTAL_MED_BED:
            let newState = [...state, action.payload];
            let totalMedBed = 0;
            newState.availableMed.forEach( medBed => {
                totalMedBed += medBed
            });
            return state
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

MapstateToProps in my Main Component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        SWMCFH: state.SWMCFH,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SWMCFHState` makes sense to me.  Your action I don't quite understand.  We need actions to `TAKE_BED` and to `RELEASE_BED`.  Those actions need to know the bed type (`A14` etc.) and the unit (`Icu` etc.).

What is the action `TOTAL_MED_BED` for?  Getting the total would be the job of a selector rather than an action.  It looks like you are returning way too much info in your action.  We don't want to have to replace the entire `availableMed` section.

You don't really need to store the `total` in state at all because you could calculate it from your selector function. If you do store it, we can make it easier to calculate by grouping the bed counts in a separate property from the total. `{total: 5, types: {A14: 1, A13: 1 .... }}`.  That way you can use `Object.values` on the `types` property and `reduce` to get the sum.

Here is my initial state.  All I did was separate the beds from the other properties like `name` and `id` and remove `available` from the unit property names.

```
const SWMCFHState = {
  id: "SWMC",
  name: "Swedish Medical Center First Hill",
  availableBeds: {
    med: {
      total: 10,
      A14: 1,
      A13: 1,
      A12: 1,
      B19: 1,
      B24: 1,
      B27: 1,
      C10: 1,
      C11: 1,
      C16: 1,
      D12: 1
    },
    tele: {
      total: 5,
      A20: 1,
      A24: 1,
      B03: 1,
      B04: 1,
      B05: 1
    },
    icu: {
      total: 3,
      C01: 1,
      C02: 1,
      C06: 1
    }
  }
};
```

The reducer code is really similar for taking and releasing a bed, so we can actually use the same action with separate action creators for both situations.

```
export const CHANGE_BED_COUNT = "CHANGE_BED_COUNT";

// internal helper action, not exported
const changeBedCount = (change) => (unit, bed) => ({
  type: CHANGE_BED_COUNT,
  payload: { change, unit, bed }
})

// functions of (unit, bed)
export const takeBed = changeBedCount( -1 ); // subtract 1
export const releaseBed = changeBedCount( 1 ); // add 1
```

You can improve this reducer by making sure that we aren't taking a bed that isn't available or releasing a bed that isn't taken.  But here are the basics.  [Immutable updates](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) can be really tricky!  This would be a lot easier with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer).

```
export const SWMCFH = (state = SWMCFHState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_BED_COUNT:
      const { unit, bed, change } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        avaiableBeds: {
          ...state.availableBeds,
          [unit]: {
            // copy all bed types
            ...state.availableBeds[unit],
            // add/subtract 1 from total
            total: state.availableBeds[unit].total + change,
            // add/subtract 1 from the selected bed type
            [bed]: state.availableBeds[unit][bed] + change
          }
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```